# Define $M$ on circular arc $BC$ satisfying that: If $K,G,H$ are the projections of $M$ on $AB,BC,CA$ then : + $MA+MB+MC+MH+MG+MK$ is maximum

Tags: geometry, derivatives, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle and inscribed a circle $ (O, R)$ . Define $M$ on circular arc $BC$ satisfying that:
If $K,G,H$  are the projections of $M$ on $AB,BC,CA$ then :

- $MA+MB+MC+MH+MG+MK$ is maximum
- $MA+MB+MC+MH+MG+MK$ is minimum
  [image]

---

With this problem, it seems hard for me to find some fixed and already known factors to solve this.
I really need you help in creating some points to take advantages of all the readings in the problem.

I think it may not easy, but if you have any helpful ideas, please show me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use GeoGebra to find M location that provides the solution (Your question is not really clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us express $MG,MH$ and $MK$ in the terms of $MA$.

Using Ptolomy theorem for $ABMC$ we get $$MA = MB+MC$$

Let $\angle BAM = x$ then $$MG = MB \sin (60-x) = MC \sin x$$ so $$MG = MA{\sin x\sin (60-x)\over \sin x+\sin (60-x)}$$Also $$MH = MA\cdot \sin(60-x) \;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;MK = MA\cdot \sin x$$

If we mark $\cos (x-30) = :t$ then the expression can be reduced to $$MA\Big(2t+2-{3\over 4t}\Big)$$

Finally, using sin theorem $$MA = 2R\sin (120-x) = 2R \cos (x-30) = 2Rt$$ we have to find the extreme points for $$f(t) := 4t^2+4t-{3\over 2}$$ where ${\sqrt{3}\over 2}\leq t\leq 1$. Since $f$ is increasing for $t\geq -{1\over 2}$ we see that

- maximum is achieved when $t=1$ i.e. $M$ is a midpoint of arc $BC$ and
- minimum is achieved when $t={\sqrt{3}\over 2}$ i.e. $M$ is either $B$ or $C$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109631/given-an-equilateral-triangle-show-that-ma-mc-mb?rq=1