# Find point $M$ on the circle such that $MA+MB+MC$ is minimum/maximum

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a basic geometry problem that I came up with while trying to solve a complex number problem in a geometric way. It looks easy but I get stuck on proving:

> Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle inscribed in a circle with center $O$. Find the point $M$ on the circle for the value $T=MA+MB+MC$ is maximum and minimum.

I already know the result (by using some software) but I want to prove it clearly.

Comment: what is the result you found? This might help us with formulating a proof? Also, on what circle is $M$ exactly?

Comment: $M$ on the circle centre $O$ too and the result is:
$T$ minimum when $M$ is $A$,$B$ or $C$.
$T$ maximum when $M$ is the symetry point of $A$,$B$ or $C$ through $O$.

Comment: Do you mean that $A,B,C$ are on a circle that has center $O$, and $M$ is also on this circle? I am a bit confused by your wording as you mention an [incircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle).

Comment: sorry for my bad english, all the point $A$, $B$, $C$ and $M$ are on circle centre $O$ and $ABC$ is equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also prove this using [the answer given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109631), which suggests using [Ptolemy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem#Equilateral_triangle). From that link we get this picture, and we know that $p+r=q$, i.e. $T=2q$:

[image: picture of situation]

So the value is minimal when $q$ is minimal on the short arc $[AB]$ (So $M$ on $A$ or $B$), and maximal when $q$ is maximal, which happens when $M$ is exactly in the middle of $A$ and $B$.